# Pandas fill null values not knowing the index of the Series with array of same shape of null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to fill some NaN values in one column of my dataframe. From what I understand from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), I should be able to pass a Pandas series to `fillna`, and Pandas will then fill my NaN's with the Series I provided.

The code is like this:

```
XTrain_pd[class_name] = XTrain_pd[class_name].fillna(pd.Series(train_pred))
```

So fill in the NaN values based on the values from `train_pred`.

I made sure that the length of `train_pred` and the number of NaN's to be filled is the same:

```
print(XTrain_pd[class_name].isna().sum(),print(train_pred.shape))
```

This outputs:

```
(9,)
9 None
```

I also printed out `XTrain_pd` before and after using fillna on the NaN values.

Left image is before `fillna`, right image is after `fillna`.

Some mysterious things happen here. Firstly, only one NaN value is imputed, in row #6. Secondly, my `pd.NA` values get converted to `np.nan` values. What is going on here?

[image: Before][image: After]

Comment: If the argument of `.fillna()` is a Series, the indices of the DataFrame and the Series are matched. So you need a Series that has indices that matches the indices of the NA rows of your DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR** Use `.loc()` to filter the nan values and replace with the predictions df.loc[df.class_name.isna(), 'class_name'] = train_pred

Consider a dataframe with two null values at index 3 and 9

```
d = {
    'col_str': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    'col_float': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
>>>
 col_str  col_float
0   a   1.0
1   b   2.0
2   c   3.0
3   d   NaN
4   e   5.0
5   f   6.0
6   g   7.0
7   h   8.0
8   i   9.0
9   j   NaN
```

if you want to replace null values with the predictions `train_pred`, just filter the `Nan` values on `col_float` and replace it with the predictions.

```
train_pred = [4.0, 10.0]

df.loc[df.col_float.isna(), 'col_float'] = train_pred
```

If you were to use `fillna()` you wourld need to specify each value for each index of the Series.